# Restrict Alpha and special characters in Text Box along with decimal precision

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Am having a requirement as to restrict alpha and special(except single dot) charaters in input field. 
Then based on the filtered value i have to some computation for other fields

My Ts file

```
@Component({
    selector: 'filter-data',
    template: `<input #input (keydown)="onKeyPress($event)" [(ngModel)]="InputValue" id="Input">`
})

onKeyPress(params: any)
    {       
        if (!this.isKeyPressedNumeric(params)) {            
            return false;
        }

    }
private isKeyPressedNumeric(event: any): boolean {
        debugger
        var inputVal = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("Input");
        var input = inputVal.value;
        input = input + event.key;
        if (input.length >= 2) {
            var txtVal = input;
            return !!/^\d*\.?\d{0,18}$/.test(txtVal);
        }

        const charCode = this.getCharCode(event);
        const charStr = event.key ? event.key : String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        return this.isCharNumeric(charStr);
    }

    private getCharCode(event: any): any {
        event = event || window.event;
        return (typeof event.which == "undefined") ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    }

    private isCharNumeric(charStr: any): boolean {
        var validation = false;

        if (charStr == ".") {
            validation = !!/\./.test(charStr);
        }
        else {
            validation = !!/\d/.test(charStr);
        }
        return validation;
    }
```

on click of backspace, the respective digit is not deleting.
Then i need to restrict user to enter only 18 digits before dot and 15 digits after dot
After the filtering of digits, i need to get the latest value for computation
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

```
if(params.key === 'Backspace') {
    return true;
}
```

---

Your `onKeyPress` function should look like this :

```
onKeyPress(params: any)
{       
    if(params.key === 'Backspace') {
        return true;
    }
    else if (!this.isKeyPressedNumeric(params)) {            
        return false;
    }
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-number-backspace)**

Comment: and also restrict user to enter only 18 digits before dot and 15 digits after dot

Comment: am testing the code and need the decimal filter also

Comment: let me modify the question

Comment: after delete i need to call another method for computation based on the updated value

Comment: in original question u can see, the updated value to be passed to another method for computation. but by your implementation am able to delete but not able to pass parameter

Comment: how to pass the modified value as parameter?

Comment: @anand , you can do that by simply (keyup)="modifiedValue($event.target.value)" , check updated demo and check in `console`

Comment: for that u need to accept the changes what i made on your answer

Comment: @anand , Done !!

Comment: could you provide decimal precision?

Comment: @anand , yeah sure but in different question :)